# Converting SQL query

Tags: perl, catalyst, dbix-class

I have an SQL query which is fetching me the data correcting from sqlplus. When I try to convert the query such that I can implement in the catalyst controller, I am getting an error message saying there is no relation between the tables Feature and Featurealias.As I am new to catalyst and DBIx::Class, I am not able to figure out what could be the probable mistake. Can any body help me fix this issue.
Below is the SQL query and the code which I a trying to implement in catalyst Controller.

```
my@sourceid=$c->model('Gene::Featurealias')->search({
                        'feature.typeid'=>4,
        },
        {
                        join=>'feature',
                        distinct=>1,
                        columns=>[qw/sourceid/]

        });
```

SQL query:

```
select distinct FeatureAlias.SourceID From FeatureAlias join Feature on FeatureAlias.FeatureID=Feature.FeatureID where Feature.TypeID=4;
```

Defined in Feature.pm

```
__PACKAGE__->has_many( "featurealias",
  "...Result::Featurealias");
```

Defined in Featurealias.pm

```
__PACKAGE__->belongs_to("featureid",
  "...::Result::Feature");
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You've created a relationship named 'featureid' in your Featurealias class but asked DBIC to join one named 'feature'.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I give featureid instead of feature,it still flags error.It would be of great help if you could elaborate more  on what you have commented, as I am new to this field. Thanks again.

Comment: Please include the whole classes instead of just the relationship definitions.